# How to reorder billing fields in WooCommerce Checkout template?

Tags: filters, plugins

I'm creating a madlib style checkout form using WooTheme's *[Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)*.

Billing fields in the checkout template `form-billing.php`are displayed with this call:

```
<?php foreach ($checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field) : ?>
<?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can change the order the fields appear?

The current (default) field order is:
first name
last name
company (hidden for me)
town/city
zipcode
country
state
email
phone

*Default order:*
[image: screenshot]

I want the fields to be in a more natural order for Americans (where I live), so:
first name
last name
company (hidden for me)
town/city
state
zipcode
country
email
phone

How can I best do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Dbranes for the answer.

Replace:

```
<?php foreach ($checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field) : ?>
<?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

With:

```
<?php 
// order the keys for your custom ordering or delete the ones you don't need
$mybillingfields=array(
    "billing_first_name",
    "billing_last_name",
    "billing_company",
    "billing_address_1",
    "billing_address_2",
    "billing_city",
    "billing_state",
    "billing_postcode",
    "billing_country",
    "billing_email",
    "billing_phone",
);
foreach ($mybillingfields as $key) : ?>
<?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $checkout->checkout_fields['billing'][$key], $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: this code is from an internal Woocommerce function. using the first answer's code [a filter] would be much better.

Comment: For me it doesn't work. The best way is to use the "priority" of each field, something like this:

$fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 10;
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 20;

Maybe it is because of new versions of Woocommerce, but I don't know.

Answer (score 31):

Same can be done through `functions.php` in your (child) theme:

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "order_fields");

function order_fields($fields) {

    $order = array(
        "billing_first_name", 
        "billing_last_name", 
        "billing_company", 
        "billing_address_1", 
        "billing_address_2", 
        "billing_postcode", 
        "billing_country", 
        "billing_email", 
        "billing_phone"

    );
    foreach($order as $field)
    {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
    }

    $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
    return $fields;

}
```

Comment: Best answer as it uses the wp/wc best practice with filtering the data before it reaches the template so no template file has to be overridden.

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: This use to work but no longer does. I think it's because the checkout JS dynamically alters the order.

Comment: The current way to do it is to assign a priority:-
`$fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 10;`
`$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 20;`

See here [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-order-of-billing-fields-on-checkout-page/](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-order-of-billing-fields-on-checkout-page/)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy into your theme and edit the template that renders the checkout form.

Adapted from the [plugin documentation](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/template-structure/):

> **Example**
>   To overide the admin order notification, copy: `woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php`
>   to
>   `yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`

**[update]**

In this file, just before the fields being printed, there's this action hook: `do_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $checkout);`.

So, it's just a matter of adding this action in the theme's `functions.php` or in a custom plugin and reordering the fields as the OP shows in his Answer. No need of overriding the template, or yes if further customizations are needed.

Comment: The template you mentioned only allows you to move `<?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_billing'); ?>` around wholesale.

Comment: I should've mention that I didn't checked the actual plugin files. Answer updated and expanded thanks to your answer.